# Report Parameter (OWNERID) cannot be changed using restful webservices

Tags: rest, business-objects-sdk

While trying to update a document properties using the restful API I cannot change the `ownerid`.

This is the result of my get request:

```
<entry>
<title type="text">document</title>
<updated>2018-03-29T10:56:51.939Z</updated>
<content type="application/xml">
<attrs>
<attr name="cuid" type="string">AWkFvt1UNShIqwJqu3U6pts</attr>
<attr name="keywords" type="string" />
<attr name="parentcuid" type="string">AaWFM3xI6bxBv9HlI5RIuyw</attr>
<attr name="created" type="string">Mar 27, 2018 5:22 PM</attr>
<attr name="name" type="string">New Document_test</attr>
<attr name="description" type="string" />
<attr name="id" type="string">12670</attr>
<attr name="type" type="string">Webi</attr>
<attr name="ownerid" type="int32">12</attr>
<attr name="updated" type="string">Mar 29, 2018 11:56 AM</attr>
<attr name="parentid" type="string">7018</attr>
 </attrs>
</content>
 </entry>
```

When trying to change the `ownerid` in a put request:

```
<title type="text">document</title>
<updated>2018-03-29T10:56:51.939Z</updated>
<content type="application/xml">
<attrs>
<attr name="cuid" type="string">AWkFvt1UNShIqwJqu3U6pts</attr>
<attr name="keywords" type="string" />
<attr name="parentcuid" type="string">AaWFM3xI6bxBv9HlI5RIuyw</attr>
<attr name="created" type="string">Mar 27, 2018 5:22 PM</attr>
<attr name="name" type="string">New Document_test</attr>
<attr name="description" type="string" />
<attr name="id" type="string">12670</attr>
<attr name="type" type="string">Webi</attr>
<attr name="ownerid" type="int32">12133</attr>
<attr name="updated" type="string">Mar 29, 2018 11:56 AM</attr>
<attr name="parentid" type="string">7018</attr>
 </attrs>
</content>
 </entry>
```

As a result the `ownerid` doesn't change.

But when trying the same thing sing a java SDK code the `ownerid` does change.
Here is the code:

```
import com.crystaldecisions.sdk.properties.*;
import com.businessobjects.qaaws.internal.ISessionMgr;
import com.crystaldecisions.sdk.exception.SDKException;
import com.crystaldecisions.sdk.framework.CrystalEnterprise;
import com.crystaldecisions.sdk.framework.IEnterpriseSession;

import com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.infostore.IInfoStore;
import com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.infostore.CePropertyID;
import com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.infostore.IInfoObject;
import com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.infostore.IInfoObjects;
import com.crystaldecisions.sdk.plugin.desktop.program.IProgramBaseEx;

public class Owner     
{        
public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable{    
com.crystaldecisions.sdk.framework.ISessionMgr sm = CrystalEnterprise.getSessionMgr();    
// args[] contains user, password, CMS host name and authentication type    
IEnterpriseSession es = sm.logon(args[0], args[1], args[2], args[3]);    
IInfoStore infoStore = (IInfoStore)es.getService("InfoStore");    
// Get the ID of the new owner    
String newOwnName = "test_Prefe";    
String query = "select si_name, si_id from ci_systemobjects where si_kind = 'user' and si_name='" + newOwnName + "'";    
IInfoObject newOwner = (IInfoObject)infoStore.query(query).get(0);    
int newOwnerId = newOwner.getID();    
// Query for the objects whose ownership should be changed    
IInfoObjects objsToChange = infoStore.query("select si_id, si_name, si_owner, si_ownerid from ci_infoobjects where SI_NAME = 'New Document_test'");    
for (Object o : objsToChange ) {    
IInfoObject objToChg = (IInfoObject)o;    
String oldOwner = objToChg.properties().getString(CePropertyID.SI_OWNER);    
// Set new owner ID. Note that changing CePropertyID.SI_OWNER has no effect; SI_OWNERID must be changed instead    
objToChg.properties().setProperty(CePropertyID.SI_`OWNERID`, newOwnerId);    
System.out.format("Changed owner on %s: %s -> %s%n", objToChg.getTitle(), oldOwner, newOwnName);    
}    
System.out.println("Saving changes...");    
infoStore.commit(objsToChange);    
System.out.println("Complete");    
infoStore = null;    
es.logoff();    
}
}
```

BI 4.2 Support Pack 4 Patch 2

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest opening an incident with SAP.  I can't think of any legitimate reason why the PUT call could not update the owner ID.